# How to pass a value to line generation function in D3

Tags: d3.js

Following code is used to generate lines in D3:

```
    var lineFn = d3.line()
        .x((d) => this.base.xAxis.scale(d.x))
        .y((d) => this.base.yAxes[0].scale(d.y));

    // series is a collection of lines I want to plot
    series = [
         {
             data: [{x: 10, y: 20}, {x: 20, y: 30}],
             yAxis: 0,   // this indicates which y-axis to use
             color: red
         },
         ...
    ];

    _.forEach(series, (line) => {
        this.base.chart.append("path")
            .datum(line.data)
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", lineFn)
            .style("stroke", line.color)
    });
```

My chart uses dual y-axes using `d3.axisLeft()` and `d3.axisRight()`.

Right now, I am hardcoding the value of which `y-axis` to use in the `lineFn`.

```
.y((d) => this.base.yAxes[0].scale(d.y)); // 0-left axis, 1-right axis
```

What I would like to do is pass that value when I call the line function, something like:

```
.attr("d", lineFn(line.yAxis))
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve what you want is simply creating two different line generators.

However, since you asked (not verbatim) *"is it possible to define the scale dynamically when calling the line generator?"*, the answer is: yes, it is possible. Let's see how to do it.

In this example, I'm using an object to store the different scales:

```
var scales = {
    yScaleLeft: d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 100])
        .range([170, 30]),
    yScaleRight: d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 200])
        .range([170, 30])
};
```

And, in the dataset, defining which scale and color should be used for each line, just as you did:

```
var data = [{
    data: [{
        x: 1,
        y: 20
    }, {
        ...
    }, {
        x: 8,
        y: 50
    }],
    yAxis: "yScaleLeft",
    color: "red"
}, {
    data: [{
        x: 3,
        y: 120
    }, {
        ...
    }, {
        x: 9,
        y: 180
    }],
    yAxis: "yScaleRight",
    color: "blue"
}];
```

Then, when calling the line generator, we set a variable (in this case, `thisScale`) to specify the scale:

```
var thisScale;

paths.attr("stroke", d => d.color)
    .attr("d", d => {
        thisScale = scales[d.yAxis]
        return line(d.data);
    })
    .attr("fill", "none");
```

Here is the demo, the red line uses a scale going from 0 to 100, the blue line uses a scale going from 0 to 200:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 200);
  
var thisScale;

var line = d3.line()
  .x(d => xScale(d.x))
  .y(d => thisScale(d.y))
  .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);

var data = [{
  data: [{
    x: 1,
    y: 20
  }, {
    x: 2,
    y: 30
  }, {
    x: 3,
    y: 10
  }, {
    x: 4,
    y: 60
  }, {
    x: 5,
    y: 70
  }, {
    x: 6,
    y: 80
  }, {
    x: 7,
    y: 40
  }, {
    x: 8,
    y: 50
  }],
  yAxis: "yScaleLeft",
  color: "red"
}, {
  data: [{
    x: 3,
    y: 120
  }, {
    x: 4,
    y: 130
  }, {
    x: 5,
    y: 10
  }, {
    x: 6,
    y: 120
  }, {
    x: 7,
    y: 40
  }, {
    x: 8,
    y: 130
  }, {
    x: 9,
    y: 180
  }],
  yAxis: "yScaleRight",
  color: "blue"
}];

var scales = {
  yScaleLeft: d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range([170, 30]),
  yScaleRight: d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 200])
    .range([170, 30])
};

var xScale = d3.scalePoint()
  .domain(d3.range(11))
  .range([30, 470])

var paths = svg.selectAll("foo")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("path");

paths.attr("stroke", d => d.color)
  .attr("d", d => {
    thisScale = scales[d.yAxis]
    return line(d.data);
  })
  .attr("fill", "none");

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

var yAxisLeft = d3.axisLeft(scales.yScaleLeft);

var yAxisRight = d3.axisRight(scales.yScaleRight);

var gX = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,170)").call(xAxis);

var gY = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(30,0)").call(yAxisLeft);

var gY2 = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(470,0)").call(yAxisRight);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

And here the same solution, but using an array (instead of an object) to store the scales, as you asked in your question:

```
yAxis: 0//indicates the left axis
yAxis: 1//indicates the right axis
```

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 200);
  
var thisScale;

var line = d3.line()
  .x(d => xScale(d.x))
  .y(d => thisScale(d.y))
  .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);

var data = [{
  data: [{
    x: 1,
    y: 20
  }, {
    x: 2,
    y: 30
  }, {
    x: 3,
    y: 10
  }, {
    x: 4,
    y: 60
  }, {
    x: 5,
    y: 70
  }, {
    x: 6,
    y: 80
  }, {
    x: 7,
    y: 40
  }, {
    x: 8,
    y: 50
  }],
  yAxis: 0,
  color: "red"
}, {
  data: [{
    x: 3,
    y: 120
  }, {
    x: 4,
    y: 130
  }, {
    x: 5,
    y: 10
  }, {
    x: 6,
    y: 120
  }, {
    x: 7,
    y: 40
  }, {
    x: 8,
    y: 130
  }, {
    x: 9,
    y: 180
  }],
  yAxis: 1,
  color: "blue"
}];

var scales = [d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range([170, 30]), d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 200])
  .range([170, 30])
];

var xScale = d3.scalePoint()
  .domain(d3.range(11))
  .range([30, 470])

var paths = svg.selectAll("foo")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("path");

paths.attr("stroke", d => d.color)
  .attr("d", d => {
    thisScale = scales[d.yAxis]
    return line(d.data);
  })
  .attr("fill", "none");

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

var yAxisLeft = d3.axisLeft(scales[0]);

var yAxisRight = d3.axisRight(scales[1]);

var gX = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,170)").call(xAxis);

var gY = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(30,0)").call(yAxisLeft);

var gY2 = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(470,0)").call(yAxisRight);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I really like this solution, it worked and I learned something new. Thank you so much for providing the working example. Really appreciate the efforts!

Comment: If you can please add a declaration for `thisScale` that would be great for someone else reading the answer.

Comment: Hi @Gerardo Furtado, as an extension to this question, can you show how to plot circles as data points using the data array above as an example?

Comment: @ChewKahMeng I'm not sure what you're asking. Please post a new question, with all the relevant details in the question itself.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I have posted a new question, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58829869/how-to-plot-data-points-on-multi-line-chart-with-multiple-y-axes) here.