# How to specify a data column as the property used in a line generator?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In d3.js it is possible to access parts of a dataset by using the syntax **d.measure** with d accessing the data property and "measure" accessing a specific field in our dataset. Based on the code I found on [bl.ocks.org](http://bl.ocks.org/JessicaFreaner/raw/7521f66f732a2bd8dcba/) I created a line chart. I however wanted to alter the function dsLineChart() in such a way that I can pass the name of the column that I want to use for visualising the values on the y-axis, i.e. **how to specify an argument dsLineChart(argument) that determines the column to use** e.g. d.measure2 instead of d.measure.

See below for the script. The dataset I have contains the columns "measure", "measure2", "measure3" and "measure4" of  which "measure" is visualised by d.measure, but I want to call e.g. dsLineChart("measure2") to use the same function but for another column.

e.g.

- Dataset

---

```
var data =  [
{group:"All",category:2011,measure:28107,measure2:53301,measure3:89015.40,measure4:138394},
{group:"All",category:2012,measure:39400,measure2:7001, measure3:55550.50,measure4:18004},
{group:"All",category:2013,measure:33894,measure2:690597,measure3:68289.50,measure4:17455},
{group:"All",category:2014,measure:55261,measure2:7172,measure3:73380.93,measure:418143} ];
```

- Script

I have created a minimal working script that can be found on the following link [Fiddle D3js line chart](http://jsfiddle.net/7qyt4ges/)

Thanks to the of feedback @GerardoFurtado the resulting script is provided in below snippet and allows for calling the function dsLineChart() with different arguments resulting in linecharts using different measures e.g. dsLineChart("measure2") vs. dsLineChart("measure").

```js
// dataset       
var lineChartData = [{
    category: 2011,
    measure: 28107,
    measure2: 53301,
    measure3: 89015.40,
    measure4: 138394
  },
  {
    category: 2012,
    measure: 39400,
    measure2: 7001,
    measure3: 55550.50,
    measure4: 18004
  },
  {
    category: 2013,
    measure: 33894,
    measure2: 690597,
    measure3: 68289.50,
    measure4: 17455
  },
  {
    category: 2014,
    measure: 55261,
    measure2: 7172,
    measure3: 73380.93,
    measure: 418143
  }
];

// layout
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 10,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 350 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// function to draw linechart
function dsLineChart(selMeasure) {
 //convert object to array
  var data = d3.values(lineChartData);
 
  var property;
 var measures = [selMeasure];

  var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, data.length - 1])
    .range([0, width]);

  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return d[selMeasure];
    })])
    .range([height, 0])
    .range([height, 0]);

  var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d, i) {
      return xScale(i);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return yScale(d[property]);
    });

  var svg = d3.select("#lineChart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr("position", "absolute")
    .attr("top", "10px")
    .attr("left", "410px")

  var plot = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .attr("id", "lineChartPlot");

  var paths = plot.selectAll(null)
    .data(measures)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      property = d;
      return line(data)
    })
    .attr("stroke", "lightgrey")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke-width", "4px");
}

dsLineChart("measure2");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="lineChart"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most *"elegant"* solution here, and probably the most idiomatic one, is nesting your data, in such a way that the y value property can have the same name for all lines.

However, this doesn't mean that what you're asking is not possible: it certainly is. You can specify what scale you pass to the line generator (for instance, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43313365/5768908)), and what property you use for each method.

For this to work, we'll first declare a variable:

```
var property;
```

That's the variable we'll use in the line generator:

```
var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d, i) {
        return xScale(i);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return yScale(d[property]);
    });
```

Now, let's get the real properties. Here I'm hardcoding them, but you can easily extract them from the data:

```
var measures = ["measure", "measure2", "measure3", "measure4"];
```

Then, we bind that array as data:

```
var paths = plot.selectAll(null)
    .data(measures)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
```

Now comes the important part: in the callback, you simply assign the value of `property`, which is used by the line generator:

```
.attr("d", function(d) {
    property = d;
    return line(data)
})
```

All together, here is your code with those changes:

```js
// dataset       
var data = [{
    group: "All",
    category: 2011,
    measure: 28107,
    measure2: 53301,
    measure3: 89015.40,
    measure4: 138394
  },
  {
    group: "All",
    category: 2012,
    measure: 39400,
    measure2: 7001,
    measure3: 55550.50,
    measure4: 18004
  },
  {
    group: "All",
    category: 2013,
    measure: 33894,
    measure2: 690597,
    measure3: 68289.50,
    measure4: 17455
  },
  {
    group: "All",
    category: 2014,
    measure: 55261,
    measure2: 7172,
    measure3: 73380.93,
    measure: 418143
  }
];
var property;
var measures = ["measure", "measure2", "measure3", "measure4"];

// layout
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 10,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 350 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// function to draw linechart
function dsLineChart() {

  var firstDatasetLineChart = data

  var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, firstDatasetLineChart.length - 1])
    .range([0, width]);

  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(firstDatasetLineChart, function(d) {
      return d.measure;
    })])
    .range([height, 0])
    .range([height, 0]);

  var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d, i) {
      return xScale(i);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return yScale(d[property]);
    });

  var svg = d3.select("#lineChart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr("position", "absolute")
    .attr("top", "10px")
    .attr("left", "410px")

  var plot = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .attr("id", "lineChartPlot");

  var paths = plot.selectAll(null)
    .data(measures)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      property = d;
      return line(data)
    })
    .attr("stroke", "lightgrey")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke-width", "4px");
}

dsLineChart();
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="lineChart"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer! It doesn'tcompletely covering the complete scope of the question but provides nice pointers and solutions! I've adjusted the code to allow passing the to be selected measure as an argument to the dsLineChart function. There however is an open issue with the yscale which causes some lines to become invisble I'll further fiddle with that. You can see the issue with measure2 which is I think caused by   "var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,d3.max(firstDatasetLineChart, function(d) { return d.measure;  })])   .range([height, 0])
    .range([height, 0]);"

Comment: Just calculate the max for all measures.

Comment: I have adjusted the code and added final solution; thank you for the help. I have created the function now as such that an argument can be passed to make the function reusable for different line charts