# How to plot data points on multi-line chart with multiple y axes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to add data points to my line chart with multiple y axes. Click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kahmeng96/osqk6Lyh/361/) for my fiddle.

```
    //after restructuring dataset array
    var data = [{
      data: [{
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      }, {
        x: 10,
        y: 10
      }, {
        x: 20,
        y: 20
      }, {
        x: 30,
        y: 30
      }, {
        x: 40,
        y: 40
      }],
      yAxis: 0,
    }, {
      data: [{
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      }, {
        x: 10,
        y: 200
      }, {
        x: 20,
        y: 300
      }, {
        x: 30,
        y: 400
      }, {
        x: 40,
        y: 500
      }],
      yAxis: 1,
    }];

    const margin = {
      left: 20,
      right: 20,
      top: 20,
      bottom: 80
    };

    const svg = d3.select('svg');
    svg.selectAll("*").remove();

    const width = 200 - margin.left - margin.right;
    const height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    const g = svg.append('g').attr('transform', `translate(${80},${margin.top})`);

    //************* Axes and Gridlines ***************
    const xAxisG = g.append('g');
    const yAxisG = g.append('g');

    xAxisG.append('text')
      .attr('class', 'axis-label')
      .attr('x', width / 3)
      .attr('y', -10)
      .style('fill', 'black')
      .text(function(d) {
      return "X Axis";
    });

    yAxisG.append('text')
      .attr('class', 'axis-label')
      .attr('id', 'yAxisLabel0')
      .attr('x', -height / 2)
      .attr('y', -15)
      .attr('transform', `rotate(-90)`)
      .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .style('fill', 'black')
      .text(function(d) {
      return "Y Axis 1";
    });

    // interpolator for X axis -- inner plot region
    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(xValueArray)])
    .range([0, width])
    .nice();

    var yScale = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      // interpolator for Y axis -- inner plot region
      var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(arr[i])])
      .range([0, height])
      .nice();
      yScale.push(y);
    }

    const xAxis = d3.axisTop()
    .scale(x)
    .ticks(5)
    .tickPadding(2)
    .tickSize(-height)

    const yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(yScale[0])
    .ticks(5)
    .tickPadding(2)
    .tickSize(-width);

    yAxisArray = new Array();
    yAxisArray.push(yAxis);
    for (var i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
      var yAxisSecondary = d3.axisLeft()
      .scale(yScale[i])
      .ticks(5)
      yAxisArray.push(yAxisSecondary);
    }

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", `translate(80,${height-80})`)
      .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .attr("id", "ySecAxis0")
      .attr("transform", "translate(80,20)")
      .call(yAxis);

    var translation = 50;
    var textTranslation = 0;
    var yLabelArray = ["Y Axis 1", "Y Axis 2"];

    //loop starts from 1 as primary y axis is already plotted
    for (var i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
      svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + translation + "," + 20 + ")")
        .attr("id", "ySecAxis" + i)
        .call(yAxisArray[i]);

      yAxisG.append('text')
        .attr('x', -height / 2)
        .attr('y', -60)
        .attr('transform', `rotate(-90)`)
        .attr("id", "yAxisLabel" + i)
        .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .style('fill', 'black')
        .text(yLabelArray[i]);

      translation -= 40;
      textTranslation += 40;
    }

    //************* Lines and Data Points ***************
    var colors = ["blue", "red"];

    var thisScale;

    var line = d3.line()
      .x(d => x(d.x))
      .y(d => thisScale(d.y))
      .curve(d3.curveLinear);

    var paths = g.selectAll("foo")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("path");

    paths.attr("stroke", function (d,i){return colors[i]})
      .attr("d", d => {
        thisScale = yScale[d.yAxis]
        return line(d.data);
      })
      .attr("stroke-width", 2)
      .attr("id", function (d,i){return "line" + i})
      .attr("fill", "none");

    var points = g.selectAll("dot")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle");

    points.attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.x)} )
      .attr("cy", function(d,i) { return yScale[i](d.y); } )
      .attr("r", 3)
      .attr("class", function (d,i){return "blackDot" + i})
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
```

Right now the console log is showing these errors: **Error:  attribute cx: Expected length, "NaN". Error:  attribute cy: Expected length, "NaN".** It seems like I am not attributing the correct cx and cy to points, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrongly. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data structure is an array of objects, each one containing an inner array with the real coordinates for the circles. Therefore, that single enter selection will not work.

With minimal refactoring, my solution here is appending groups according to the objects, and then, for each one, appending circles according to the inner arrays. For that cumbersome `yScale` to work you cannot rely on the circle's indices anymore, so I'm using a local variable here:

```
var pointsGroup = g.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    local.set(this, yScale[i])
    return colors[i];
  });

var points = pointsGroup.selectAll(null)
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.data
  })
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return x(d.x)
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d, i) {
    return local.get(this)(d.y);
  })
  //etc...
```

Here is the code with those changes:

```js
var local = d3.local();
var xValueArray = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40];
var arr = [
  [0, 10, 20, 30, 40],
  [0, 200, 300, 400, 500]
];
var dataset = [
  [{
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  }, {
    x: 10,
    y: 10
  }, {
    x: 20,
    y: 20
  }, {
    x: 30,
    y: 30
  }, {
    x: 40,
    y: 40
  }],
  [{
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  }, {
    x: 10,
    y: 200
  }, {
    x: 20,
    y: 300
  }, {
    x: 30,
    y: 400
  }, {
    x: 40,
    y: 500
  }]
];

var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  data.push({
    "data": dataset[i],
    "yAxis": i
  })
}
console.log(data);

//after restructuring dataset array
var data = [{
  data: [{
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  }, {
    x: 10,
    y: 10
  }, {
    x: 20,
    y: 20
  }, {
    x: 30,
    y: 30
  }, {
    x: 40,
    y: 40
  }],
  yAxis: 0,
}, {
  data: [{
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  }, {
    x: 10,
    y: 200
  }, {
    x: 20,
    y: 300
  }, {
    x: 30,
    y: 400
  }, {
    x: 40,
    y: 500
  }],
  yAxis: 1,
}];

const margin = {
  left: 20,
  right: 20,
  top: 20,
  bottom: 80
};

const svg = d3.select('svg');
svg.selectAll("*").remove();

const width = 200 - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
const g = svg.append('g').attr('transform', `translate(${80},${margin.top})`);

//************* Axes and Gridlines ***************
const xAxisG = g.append('g');
const yAxisG = g.append('g');

xAxisG.append('text')
  .attr('class', 'axis-label')
  .attr('x', width / 3)
  .attr('y', -10)
  .style('fill', 'black')
  .text(function(d) {
    return "X Axis";
  });

yAxisG.append('text')
  .attr('class', 'axis-label')
  .attr('id', 'yAxisLabel0')
  .attr('x', -height / 2)
  .attr('y', -15)
  .attr('transform', `rotate(-90)`)
  .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .style('fill', 'black')
  .text(function(d) {
    return "Y Axis 1";
  });

// interpolator for X axis -- inner plot region
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(xValueArray)])
  .range([0, width])
  .nice();

var yScale = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  // interpolator for Y axis -- inner plot region
  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(arr[i])])
    .range([0, height])
    .nice();
  yScale.push(y);
}

const xAxis = d3.axisTop()
  .scale(x)
  .ticks(5)
  .tickPadding(2)
  .tickSize(-height)

const yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(yScale[0])
  .ticks(5)
  .tickPadding(2)
  .tickSize(-width);

yAxisArray = new Array();
yAxisArray.push(yAxis);
for (var i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
  var yAxisSecondary = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(yScale[i])
    .ticks(5)
  yAxisArray.push(yAxisSecondary);
}

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", `translate(80,${height-80})`)
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("id", "ySecAxis0")
  .attr("transform", "translate(80,20)")
  .call(yAxis);

var translation = 50;
var textTranslation = 0;
var yLabelArray = ["Y Axis 1", "Y Axis 2"];

//loop starts from 1 as primary y axis is already plotted
for (var i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + translation + "," + 20 + ")")
    .attr("id", "ySecAxis" + i)
    .call(yAxisArray[i]);

  yAxisG.append('text')
    .attr('x', -height / 2)
    .attr('y', -60)
    .attr('transform', `rotate(-90)`)
    .attr("id", "yAxisLabel" + i)
    .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .style('fill', 'black')
    .text(yLabelArray[i]);

  translation -= 40;
  textTranslation += 40;
}

//************* Mouseover ***************
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
  .append("div")
  .style("opacity", 0)
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("background-color", "white")
  .style("border", "solid")
  .style("border-width", "1px")
  .style("border-radius", "5px")
  .style("padding", "10px")
  .style("position", "absolute")

var mouseover = function(d) {
  tooltip
    .html("x: " + d.x + "<br/>" + "y: " + d.y)
    .style("opacity", 1)
    .style("left", (d3.mouse(this)[0] + 90) + "px")
    .style("top", (d3.mouse(this)[1]) + "px")
}

// A function that change this tooltip when the leaves a point: just need to set opacity to 0 again
var mouseleave = function(d) {
  tooltip
    .transition()
    .duration(200)
    .style("opacity", 0)
}

//************* Lines and Data Points ***************
var colors = ["blue", "red"];

var thisScale;

var line = d3.line()
  .x(d => x(d.x))
  .y(d => thisScale(d.y))
  .curve(d3.curveLinear);

var paths = g.selectAll("foo")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("path");

paths.attr("stroke", function(d, i) {
    return colors[i]
  })
  .attr("d", d => {
    thisScale = yScale[d.yAxis]
    return line(d.data);
  })
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("id", function(d, i) {
    return "line" + i
  })
  .attr("fill", "none");

var pointsGroup = g.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    local.set(this, yScale[i])
    return colors[i];
  });

var points = pointsGroup.selectAll(null)
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.data
  })
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return x(d.x)
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d, i) {
    return local.get(this)(d.y);
  })
  .attr("r", 3)
  .attr("class", function(d, i) {
    return "blackDot" + i
  })
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .on("mouseover", mouseover)
  .on("mouseleave", mouseleave)

//plot lines (hard-coding)
/*var lineFunction1 = d3.line()
.x(function(d) {
  return x(d.x);
})
.y(function(d) {
  return yScale[0](d.y);
})
.curve(d3.curveLinear);

var lineFunction2 = d3.line()
.x(function(d) {
  return x(d.x);
})
.y(function(d) {
  return yScale[1](d.y);
})
.curve(d3.curveLinear);

var path1 = g.append("path")
.attr("class", "path" + 0)
.attr("id", "line" + 0)
.attr("d", lineFunction1(data[0]))
.attr("stroke", "blue")
.attr("stroke-width", 2)
.attr("fill", "none")
.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

var path2 = g.append("path")
.attr("class", "path" + 1)
.attr("id", "line" + 1)
.attr("d", lineFunction2(data[1]))
.attr("stroke", "red")
.attr("stroke-width", 2)
.attr("fill", "none")
.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");*/

//plot lines and points using for loop
/*for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  var lineFunction = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.x);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return yScale[i](d.y);
  })
  .curve(d3.curveLinear);

  var paths = g.append("path")
  .attr("class", "path" + i)
  .attr("id", "line" + i)
  .attr("d", lineFunction(data[i]))
  .attr("stroke", colors[i])
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")

  //plot a circle at each data point
  g.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(data[i])
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.x)} )
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale[i](d.y); } )
    .attr("r", 3)
    .attr("class", "blackDot" + i)
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mouseleave", mouseleave)
}*/

//************* Legend ***************
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")

legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width + 65)
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return 30 + i * 20;
  })
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 4)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return colors[i];
  })

legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width + 60)
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return 30 + i * 20;
  })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text(function(d, i) {
    return "Value" + (i + 1);
  })
  .on("click", function(d, i) {
    // Determine if current line is visible
    let opacity = d3.select("#line" + i).style("opacity");
    let newOpacity;
    if (opacity == 0) {
      newOpacity = 1;
    } else {
      newOpacity = 0
    }
    d3.select("#line" + i).style("opacity", newOpacity);
    d3.selectAll(".blackDot" + i).style("opacity", newOpacity);
    d3.select("#ySecAxis" + i).style("opacity", newOpacity);
    d3.select("#yAxisLabel" + i).style("opacity", newOpacity);
  });

//************* Zoom & Brush***************
const margin2 = {
  left: 80,
  right: 0,
  top: 80,
  bottom: 0
};
const height2 = height - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;
var xZoom = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
var yZoom = d3.scaleLinear().range([height2, 0]);

var xAxis2 = d3.axisTop(xZoom);

var brush = d3.brushX()
  .extent([
    [0, 0],
    [width, height2]
  ])
  .on("brush end", brushed);

var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
  .translateExtent([
    [0, 0],
    [width, height]
  ])
  .extent([
    [0, 0],
    [width, height]
  ])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);

var clip = svg.append("defs").append("svg:clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("svg:rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 0);

xZoom.domain(x.domain());
yZoom.domain(y.domain());

var context = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "context")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + 125 + ")");

context.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
  .call(xAxis2);

context.append("g")
  .attr("class", "brush")
  .call(brush)
  .call(brush.move, x.range());

function brushed() {
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") return;
  var s = d3.event.selection || xZoom.range();
  x.domain(s.map(xZoom.invert, xZoom));
  svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
  //svg.select(".path0").attr("d", lineFunction1(data[0]));
  //svg.select(".path1").attr("d", lineFunction2(data[1]));
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    //svg.select(".path" + i).attr("d", lineFunction(data[i]));
    g.selectAll(".blackDot" + i)
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return x(d.x);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return yScale[i](d.y);
      })
      .attr("r", 3)
  }
}

function zoomed() {
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return;
  var t = d3.event.transform;
  x.domain(t.rescaleX(xZoom).domain());
  svg.select(".x.axis").transiton(t).call(xAxis);
  //svg.select(".path0").transiton(t).attr("d", lineFunction1(data[0]));
  //svg.select(".path1").transiton(t).attr("d", lineFunction2(data[1]));
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    //svg.select(".path" + i).attr("d", lineFunction(data[i]));
    g.selectAll(".blackDot" + i)
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return x(d.x);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return yScale[i](d.y);
      })
      .attr("r", 3)
  }
}
```

```css
.xy_chart {
  position: relative;
  left: 70px;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg class="xy_chart"></svg>
```

Pay attention to the fact that one of the circles has an incorrect `cy` value. So, I'd suggest you to change your y scale approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, why is there an incorrect cy value at (10, 0) when my data set is correct at (10,10)?

Comment: Because of your `zoomed` function. Did you read what I wrote in the last paragraph?

Comment: Yup I did, just couldn't figure out what caused it. By any chance, do you know of a solution to zooming in the lines and points? Or do I have to open another question?

Comment: @ChewKahMeng Yes, unfortunately you have to post another question: the comments section is just for clarifications. Also, please notice that you cannot just ask a question with several issues, just to save time: that question would be closed as too broad. Here on S.O. we keep **one problem per question**.

Comment: Noted. @GerardoFurtado, I have opened another question regarding the toggling of points [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58830800/how-to-toggle-data-points-on-and-off-along-with-lines-in-multi-line-chart). Hope you can provide some insights, thank you!

Comment: Hi @GerardoFurtado, do you have any suggestions changing my y scale approach? I really can't think of anything else as multiple y axes will mean that I need multiple y scales to draw them. I need the chart to be dynamic as well, which means I cannot manually define the scales and hard-code.

Comment: Hi @GerardoFurtado, can you explain why there is an incorrect cy value? I have commented out the relevant code in the zoomed function and the data points are plotted correctly. I don't quite see how my y scale approach causes this incorrect value.

Comment: The index for each circle is not the same of the index of each group. So, as I said before, avoid selecting the scale by indices.

Comment: Gotcha, then do you have any idea how I can plot multiple y axes dynamically using another approach instead of selecting the scale by indices?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't pay attention to that.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the help anyway. Perhaps you can help me with another question I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58741551/how-to-implement-zoom-and-brush-function-correctly-to-lines-and-data-points-in-c)?